# Closed lists for Country Codes, Languages, Currencies, etc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, constants

What's considered to be a best practice for managing and handling a closed-list of countries, languages, currencies, etc?
We want to be able to consume the data across all of our services

We were thinking of having a NuGet package that will contain Enums, and to consume it wherever needed.
I've seen that some people use tables to manage that data, but since it's constant I don't see a reason for why doing it in that manner. This is data that changes (maybe) once in a decade.

Also, is there already a well known Nuget package containing some of these definitions already? Tried to search for it, but no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Always use the correct standardized ISO codes to refer to these. Do not try to implement your own list/pointers, it will only added complexity.

Comment: @Igor Definitely. I have no intention of reinventing the wheel. that's why I wonder if someone has done this job already and built a package that contains all the standardized defenitions.

Comment: It's not really constants. Countries may change names, new countries may be declared, countries may stop existing, and so does currencies and even languages... Keeping this data in a database does have it's advantages.

Comment: @ZoharPeled It's not really configuration also. The frequency of changes in countries, languages etc is extremely low. 
If data changes once in 5+ years, I'd rather have an enum and change it if needed than having the overhead of writing and reading it from the DB.
Also, a change is needed only if my application now wants to support that new country / currency / language / etc, which might take time for that to happen anyway.

Comment: I agree it's a very low frequency change, but it can still happen. I didn't say not to use constants or enums, just pointed out the fact that it's not really constants.

Comment: Agreed, note taken

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use packages to do this, then take a look at the results below. However, almost all apps I've seen/worked on generally use services or a database to retrieve this info rather than a nuget or a class containing constants.

**Country Codes**

This is the best I could find (with over 19,000 downloads): [ISO3166](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ISO3166/)

**Currency Codes**

Two packages with <1000 downloads: [Search results for ISO4217](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22ISO4217%22)

**Language Codes**

One package with <1000 downloads: [Search results for ISO639](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22iso639%22)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into these packages and update if I ended up using them / If I find anything else.